# mapping a dispatch to props when using class

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to dispatch a redux action when an element is clicked. Here is how I currently have things set up

### the action

```
export function removeItem(idx) {
  // remove the item at idx

  return {
    type: "DESTROY_ITEM",
    payload: {idx: idx}
  }
}
```

### container component

```
import ItemUi from '../ui/Item';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { removeItem } from '../../actions'

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return({
    destroyItem: (index) => {
      dispatch(
        removeItem(index)
      )
    }
  })
}


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ItemUi)
```

### ui component

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Item extends Component {

  // ... methods removed for length

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <span 
          className="btn btn-primary btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-trash"
          onClick={() => {this.props.destroyItem(this.props.index)}}></span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

DestroyItem.propTypes = {
    onRemoveItem: PropTypes.func
}

export default Item
```

### the top level component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Item from './Item'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="container">
              <NewItem/>
              <ClearAll/>
              <div className="panel-group" id="accordion">
                {this.props.item.map(this.eachItem)} // <-- renders each item
              </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

When the user clicks the span element shown in the `Item` ui component I want to fire the `destroyItem` action passing in the component's `index` prop. Instead I get the error

`TypeError: _this2.props.destroyItem is not a function`

Can you please provide some guidance on how I should do this? Let me know if there is any other useful context I can provide.

Comment: can you try logging this.props before the return statement in Item component

Comment: Can you show us how you render "Item" in your app?

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara the `render` for `Item` is displayed above.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri when I log `this.props` `destroyItem` is _not_ included. Any idea why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    destroyItem: removeItem
}
```

Comment: This is a valid answer, and the suggested approach.  Passing an object full of action creators will automatically bind each of them to `dispatch`, and since the original example just forwards the `index` parameter straight to `removeItem`, this will produce the same behavior.  I highly recommend the use of the object shorthand syntax for `mapDispatch` wherever possible, rather than explicitly writing a `mapDispatch` function.  (Source: I'm a Redux maintainer.)

Comment: @markerikson is correct.  After reading the react-redux docs for connect, the shorthand is superior to using bindActionCreators.

Comment: Yup.  (Technically, the object shorthand just calls `bindActionCreators` under the hood, exactly as you had in your original answer.)

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried implementing this change but `this.props.destroyItem` is `undefined`. Any idea why?

Comment: The code you've written above looks correct, so are you sure you're importing `removeItem` using the correct path to the action file?

Comment: @stoebelj are you rendering the container instead of the presentational component?

Comment: @KenGregory good idea, but no, I double checked and the presentation component is indeed being rendered.

Comment: @stoebelj if you're rendering the presentational component instead of the container, it will never receive the mapped actions, which would explain your issue.  You need to render the container.

Comment: ah of course! that makes perfect sense. good catch. I you'd like to write up an answer I will be happy to approve

Comment: That's ok.  This answer is the one to accept.  The issue I helped with here is just a small oversight.